Einstein Activity Related Records
I have read a lot on EAC over the last few days,
I was really interested in logging emails sent from the system to the custom object I'm sending it from.
I know you can't as the emails are stored in a 3rd party but what I've found is can't usually means .. ' you can't but there is some extremely time consuming work around for something that should be done out of the box! ' Which is just what I'm looking for.
All i need is to create a task or even a note , Chatter just anything to say this email was sent from this record at this time. just something to indicate a email was sent.
the inability to link Emails sent from custom objects is just ridiculous i cant fathom how this seemed like a good idea but it is what it is for now.
Cheers

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/411535/determine-latest-scheduled-event-between-sf-events-and-einstein-activity-capture shows you how to do a bit of that magic. Use that as your starting point and go from there.
